# AngularJS: app hangs with error '10 $digest() iterations reached'

Tags: angularjs

My Angular app has the following code:

index.jade:

```
doctype 5
html
    head

    body(ng-app='app')
        div(ng-controller='EventController')
            div(ng-repeat='event in list()')
                h2 {{event.name}}
                h3 {{event.location}}

            h2 Create new event
            label(for='name') Name:
            input(ng-model='name')

            label(for='location') Location:
            input(ng-model='location')
            button(ng-click='create()') Submit

        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js')
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular-resource.js')

        script(src= 'javascripts/app.js')
```

app.coffee:

```
app = angular.module 'app', ['ngResource']

EventsFactory = ($resource, $q)->
    url = 'http://localhost:3000/events'
    resource = $resource(url)
    resourceWithId = $resource("#{url}/:id", {id: '@id'})

    list = (events)->
        deferred = $q.defer()
        resource.get(
            (events)-> 
                deferred.resolve events
            ,(response)-> 
                deferred.reject response 
            )
        return deferred.promise

    create = (event)->
        deferred = $q.defer()
        resource.save(
            event
            ,(response)->
                deferred.resolve response
            ,(response)->
                deferred.reject response
            )
        return deferred.promise  

    ret =  
        'list': list
        'create': create
    return ret

app.factory 'EventsFactory', EventsFactory


EventController = ($scope, EventsFactory)->
    $scope.event = {}

    $scope.list = (events)->
        EventsFactory.list(events).then(
            (events)-> 
                console.log events
            ,(response)-> 
                console.log response
            )

    $scope.create = (event)->
        EventsFactory.create(event).then(
            (response)-> 
                console.log 'success', response
            ,(response)->
                console.log 'failure', response
            )
app.controller 'EventController', EventController
```

But when I go to the homepage, the app hangs and the console has an error message beginning with: 10 $digest() iterations reached. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not call the `list()` method on your `ng-repeat`.

What happens is that the `ng-repeat` directive re-evaluates the model as it is populated and results in indefinite iterations.

You will need to assign a `$scope` variable and use that instead.

Pardon the javascript, not fluent in coffee.

```
$scope.theList = $scope.list();
```

Then in your html, change:

```
ng-repeat="event in list()"
```

to

```
ng-repeat="event in theList"
```

Comment: thanks! That worked, but now I'm running into another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239655/angularjs-app-not-getting-data-from-get-request

Answer (score 0):

you should assign the result of list to a a scope variable like this

```
$scope.events=$scope.list();
```

and then you can use this variable in ng-repeat

```
   div(ng-repeat='event in events')
            h2 {{event.name}}
            h3 {{event.location}}
```